# need JS help - watch google sheets column, send email for updated value via gmail

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I need to have an email sent to 3 people when column E is updated on a specific tab of the sheet with the value 'TRUE'. I have found a lot regarding how to cite the spreadsheet, but nothing on how to direct it to a particular tab... This sheet has two tabs.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! I have tried this: (PIPELINE is the tab name.)

```js
function sendEmails() {
  
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PIPELINE");
var sheetNameToWatch = "PIPELINE";
var columnNumberToWatch = 5; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var valueToWatch1 = "TRUE";
  
if(column[5] = 'TRUE')
  
 //Define Notification Details
 var recipients = "kessla.sloan@skysmb.com, email@email.com";
 var subject = "TEST Update"+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "google sheet update - TEST";
 //Send the Email
 GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried :)

Comment: I tried the following (I'm sure it's a train wreck, I'm new at this)   PIPELINE is the tab name.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Doesn't even look like it can run - `column` is undefined, so accessing property `[5]` from it should throw an error. Further, you are performing an assignment operation, not a comparison, so that will always execute. Even further, you have no braces around the conditional body, so only the very next statement (in which `recipients` is defined) would be conditionally executed - the remaining statements would always be executed no matter the result of the `if` test. You need to go back to your Javascript textbooks and tutorials - it isn't our duty to teach you language fundamentals.

Comment: Once you get your Javascript operators and loop syntax under control, please review the Apps Script documentation on triggers and the Spreadsheet service.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to run the script every time there is an edit to the sheet, you should use the `onEdit(e)` trigger.

```
function onEdit(e){
    sendEmails(e.range);
}
```

The param `e` of this trigger contains the range of the edit, so you can check easily the column and the sheet in your if.

```
function sendEmails(range) {
    var sheetNameToWatch = "PIPELINE";
    var columnNumberToWatch = 5; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
    var valueToWatch1 = "TRUE";

    //here you check if all the requirements are met
    var rightSheet = range.getSheet().getName() == sheetNameToWatch;
    //the == are used for comparaison, while = are used only for assignment.
    var rightColumn = range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch;
    var rightValue = range.getValue() == valueToWatch1;

    // the && are "and" operators, so that the script run only of the 3 conditions are met.
    if(rightSheet && rightColumn && rightvalue){ //don't forget the brackets here
         //Define Notification Details
         var recipients = "kessla.sloan@skysmb.com, email@email.com";
         var subject = "TEST Update"+ range.getSheet().getName();
         var body = "google sheet update - TEST";
         //Send the Email
         GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this question deserves a "here you go" answer - OP has a ton to learn yet. At minimum, you probably should link to every operator and concept in a developer reference.

Comment: For once the OP actually showed some code and seems to have the will to understand how to do it, that's enough to deserve at least some guidelines IMHO. I tried to make my answer as instructive as possible.

Comment: @LioraHaydont thank you, this really helps! I'm learning... And it clears up a lot for me.

Comment: @tehhowch  YES I do have a ton to learn!  But I'm just going to dive in and learn as I go. I found the Google Apps reference and have been using that today, but if you have another learning resource you think would help I'm all ears! I'll take anything I can get.